# Can't paste images on clipboard into Pinta on Mac

Tags: mac, pinta

I'm running Pinta (the paint program) on Mac OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion). When I copy an image to the clipboard from another program and then try to paste the image into Pinta, I get an error from Pinta that the clipboard doesn't contain an image. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's a year later and it looks like the problem still exists.  The one workaround I noticed is to use the screenshot option under the file menu, and then crop the area you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use ClipBuddy for a free trial, It is a Mac clipboard manager and history Extender for Mac OS X

It can record everything you cut or copy to the Mac Clipboard, and provides multiple ways to view, edit and paste them to any app. These clips can be images, text or a mix of them (rich text, like PDFs and HTML).

Here is the link: http://www.ondesoft.com

Hope it can help you.